# angular $watch screen size with $mdMedia from service/factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

How can i get this function:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
            return $mdMedia('md');
        }, function watchCallback(newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.detectScreen = $mdMedia('max-width: 1280px');
        })
```

which at the moment sits in my controller into a service/factory, so i can use it in multiple controllers.

```
   .factory('MyFactory', [
        '$rootScope',
        '$mdMedia',
       function ($rootScope, $mdMedia) {

           return {
               detectScreen: function (param) {
                ***///get the function to work from here///***
               }
           }

       }
    ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the function in the factory without a watch:

```
app.factory('MyFactory', ['$mdMedia',
   function ($mdMedia) {
       return {
           detectScreen: function () {
               return $mdMedia('max-width: 1280px');
           };
       }
   }
]);
```

In the controllers, use the `$doCheck` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) to keep the scope variable up to date:

```
app.controller("myController", function(myFactory, $scope) {
    this.$doCheck = function () {
        $scope.detectScreen = myFactory.detectScreen();
    };
});
```

Comment: Describe the problem. What version of Angular are you using? What error message are you getting? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: i am using angular 1.6.1, when i implement your method it does not detect the screen size. thats all, no error nothing...

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue my self. To whom it may concerns, here is the answer.
put this in your controller:

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
            return CmsFactory.detectScreen();
        }, function watchCallback(small) {
            $scope.detectScreen = small;
        })
```

And this in your factory:

```
return {
        detectScreen: function () {
            return $mdMedia('md');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could move the `$watch` to the `app.run()` and emit an event when it changes that can be caught by your controllers.

Comment: sorry new to angular, you would have to provide some code example, so i can follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this answer when I was doing some research. My reputation isn't high enough to post a comment, but to answer jhon dano's question to ookadoo, I think he means this:

if you inject $mdMedia into your controller, you can use a watch to update a scope variable when the screen size changes.

The watch would look like this:

```
    $scope.ScreenIsXs = false;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $mdMedia('xs');
        }, function watchCallback(response) {
            //console.log(response); //test code
            $scope.ScreenIsXs = response;
    });
```

Then you could use the $scope variable to drive an ng-if in your html:

```
    <div ng-if="ScreenIsXs">I only show when your window is very small! </div>
```

This would be useful for simple applications that wouldn't required a factory/service. That said, your question directly stated that you needed a service/factory, so I'm not sure how useful the response would have been prior to you finding the solution.

Anyway, I hope this clarifies ookadoo's response for anyone else who stumbles across these answers in the future.